# Code location in column layout in Quarto revealjs

Tags: r, quarto, reveal.js

I am trying to use the `output-location: column` option in a Quarto reveal.js presentation.

One problem arises when there are multiple outputs from the same chunk, in which case only the first part of the code is shown on the left side, and the other part continues below the first output.

Is there a way to put all code on the right side, and all output on the left?

Reproducible example:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| echo: true
1:10

10:1 #This should be on the left side
```

I would like all code to be on the left side, and all output on the right.
````

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `#| results: hold` to your code block options to hold all text output to the end of the chunk, e.g.:

````
---
format: revealjs
---

## A title

```{r}
#| output-location: column
#| results: hold
#| echo: true
1:10

10:1 #This should be on the left side
```
````

This gives:

[image: slides]